# What is the equivalent of '||' (concat) in Entitymanager java query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, entitymanager, concatenation

I would like to rewrite an oracle stored procedure to java code, to select data with concatenated values in a query string to compare the following way:

```
 Query qString = 
                        "SELECT Obj " +
                        "FROM MyTable Obj2 WHERE ( Obj2.value1 || Obj2.value2 ) in " +
                        "(SELECT Obj2.value1 || MAX(Obj2.value2) FROM MyTable Obj2 WHERE Obj2.value2 >= :param GROUP BY Obj2.value1) " +
                        "ORDER BY Obj.value2, Obj.value1";

                        query = entityManager.createQuery(qString);
                        query.setParameter("param ", param );
```

When I run the query as a webservice on weblogic server I got error with the '|' character.
What can I use instead of the || operator to get the same result?

Comment: It is invalid jpa query. However, I couldnt understand the query. `SELECT Obj2.value1 || MAX(Obj2.value2)` is concatenation ?

Comment: didn't the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @vels4j Yes, it is in Oracle.

Comment: @vels4j: that's perfectly valid. The (standard) SQL concatenation operator is `||` although some DBMS chose to ignore that standard.

Comment: I've removed two closing parentheses which were obviously incorrect. Since these parentheses do not effect your question I did it as edit instead of an answer and leaving this comment here so you are aware of this change. If @nos solution works for you (and I think it should) then accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Persistence Query Language provides the [CONCAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun)() function, so you should be able to write  `Obj2.value1 || Obj2.value2` as  `CONCAT(Obj2.value1, Obj2.value2)`

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [...], line 1, column 43: unexpected token [CONCAT].
       
Caused by: NoViableAltException(16@[646:1: conditionalPrimary returns [Object node] : ( ( LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET conditionalExpression )=> LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET n= conditionalExpression RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET | n= simpleConditionalExpression );])

Comment: I mark your solution right, becouse you answered correclty my question :) My fault I was asking the wrong question to solve my problem >: [